# Something not quite right with my design

Tags: website-design, icons, font-sizes

There's something not quite right [here](http://oo.apphb.com/Blog), and I'm not sure what.
Should "Blog" (the title of the page) be bigger? If so, why? It seems too small, yet it's not incredibly important either.  Additionally, the RSS and StackOverflow icons seem out of place. Perhaps the fact that there's only 2 of them?
[image]

My Question: What's the best way to display the two circled parts in the image above, and why?
If you want to throw in any other criticisms of the design, that's fine too. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Lose the circled 'Blog' word.  It's interloping into the prime position.  You've already got 'Blog' in the menu.  Show that it is the blog that is selected there.

If you want to do more to say it's a blog you can below the title in smaller print say "a rambling weblog by Thomas Shields", or whatever other byline you want to give yourself.  With that 'blog' word gone, move the title up and to the left.

- Keep the icons in the top right.

With the title moved up, they're not taking up precious vertical space.  They don't look too big to me - they seem fine.  If you later decide they are less important than you thought they were you can demote them to the footer.

You're trying to create a relaxed informal impression with your choice of font and graphics - rather than a slick impersonal corporate website - and I think you're achieving that fine.

Comment: *slaps head* of course! Why didn't i think of that... thank you! With that gone everything fits into position so much nicer.